# React-native-maps failed to install

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am new to react-native and I want to install react-native-maps. However whenever I run `npm install react-native-maps --save` in the project folder, the project breaks with `node_modules/react-native` become empty with only an empty folder `node_modules` inside. I am following the installation guide from the official github now and using react-native 0.55.3.

Below attached with a dump when I call `npm install react-native-maps --save`:

screen_dump: react-native-maps install failure:

[image]

Comment: What is your npm version?

Comment: from npm --version it tells 5.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue which is [fixed with v5.7.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/8279515903cfa3026cf7096189485cdf29f74a8f) *(As far as I know. Didn't try it myself)*.

After updating your npm to a newer version, you should delete `node_modules` and do a clean install with `npm install` to reinstall all necessary packages.

One other option is to use [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). I think it is a little better tool for package management. *(Personal preference. You don't have to use it)*. If you decide to use yarn, you should still delete `node_modules` and do a clean install with `yarn install`

Comment: Thanks, obviously I am so noob that didnt know how to upgrade npm properly.

Also, will try out the yarn too. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Install yarn package manager from the following link
[enter link description here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)

Use following command to install the package.

```
yarn add react-native-maps
```

This might be works. Yarn packager is better than npm for me.